# Scroll through multiple Lists (Horizontal)

Tags: java, android

i'm looking for an option to scroll through multiple lists (horizontally) like in the Picture in the attachment.  You have the possibility to swipe left or Right to get to the next listview. On top there should be some buttons to click or to scroll

I tried putting ListViews in something like this Code but it doesn't work properly.

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="250">




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0px">



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/Black"
                android:text="hallo"
                android:textColor="@color/White">

            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/Black"
                android:text="hallo"
                android:textColor="@color/White">
            </Button>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/0533hLNk/Unbenannt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The Tool I was looking for is a ViewPager.